# How to stop word hover popups?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

[image]I am not sure what they are called but often when you read articles there are links that when you hovers display a little box. It's not an actual popup, but a positioned element on the page.

I often move the cursor along as I am reading and I usually hit several in one paragraph each covering what I am trying to read. I am then distracted, taken out of what I am currently reading to click the close on the box, then I have to start at the beginning of the sentence often, triggering it again.

I guess I could learn to not follow along with the cursor, but it's a habit. Is there anyway to disable these?

Answer (score 2):

[Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1865/) or [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/722/) is your friend. Adblock Plus is also available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=de), for NoScript I don't know.

Comment: Chrome's version of NoScript is called [ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf). But by the looks of it the issue is malware related, so I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing this on sites you previously did not see, you might have a spyware add-on installed.  For Internet Explorer, go to Start -> Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Programs Tab -> Manage Add-Ons button, and disable anything that isn't signed by Microsoft, Adobe, or Sun Microsystems.

Answer (score 0):

Some news sites use third-party services to add links to specific words. Because the main site uses an external javascript file to show the links, blocking requests to specific providers can help.

Take a look at the [JavaScript Blacklist](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/emcepjkdiiaenmoaghcfghjjppbkbhnf?hl=en) extension for Chrome.